# Can Xcode insert the version number into a library's filename when building?

Tags: xcode

If I am building a dynamic library called `Awesome`, Xcode outputs the built product as `libAwesome.dylib`. Is there a way to have Xcode insert the filename, so it gets built as `libAwesome.1.0.0.dylib`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set your `Product Name` to `Awesome.${DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION}`.

`DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION` is set by `Current Library Version` in the build settings.

Oh, and to see a list of all such environment variables, just make a new `Run Script Build Phase`, leave it empty, but check the "Show environment variables in build log" box, and then build. If you show the log for that build phase, it'll show all the environment variables along with their values. And then you can use them in the same way as above.

Comment: Found example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number