# Xcode-Increment build number only during ARCHIVE?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I have found a few other posts that show how to add a script to increment the build number with a script:

[Better way of incrementing build number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258344/xcode-better-way-of-incrementing-build-number)

[Xcode project's "Build number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371345/xcode-projects-build-number)

[Can Xcode insert the version number into a library's filename when building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694070/can-xcode-insert-the-version-number-into-a-librarys-filename-when-building)

But what I want to do, is only increase the build number when I use ARCHIVE (both before and after).

Example:
If current build number is 21, then when I choose Product > Archive the build number will be increased to 22, it will go through its process of building and creating the Archive file with the build number of 22, and then when it is finished archiving, it will increase the build number to 23.

Comment: You want to add two to the build number every time that you archive it?

Comment: I want to add 1 before it's archived then add 1 after its archived. So in the example above, the archive itself will have build number 22. But I do not want to increase build number everytime I build it, only when I archive it.

Comment: Thanks!  I found this question while making my own archive script and love your "increment the build number twice" idea.  I ended up incorporating it into mine: https://github.com/musictheory/rchook (Feel free to copy if it helps you)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Add the following script, as in the example listed in the first link that you posted, BUT do it twice.  Once at the beginning of the build and once at the end:

```
if [ $CONFIGURATION == Release ]; then
    echo "Bumping build number..."
    plist=${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}

# increment the build number (ie 115 to 116)
    buildnum=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${plist}")
    if [[ "${buildnum}" == "" ]]; then
        echo "No build number in $plist"
        exit 2
    fi

    buildnum=$(expr $buildnum + 1)
    /usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleVersion $buildnum" "${plist}"
    echo "Bumped build number to $buildnum"

else
    echo $CONFIGURATION " build - Not bumping build number."
fi
```

Many thanks to the authors of the questions that you have linked to in your question for the information that got me started on this answer!

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks! Works perfect. In Xcode 4.2 you do not even need to create the script in a directory somewhere, you can just copy and paste it right into the Build Phase section itself.

Comment: Ok, one correction.. In Xcode 4.2, it needs to be `== Release` instead of `== Archive`

Comment: Thanks, corrected!  That's actually what I had but thought that it was for something else, lol.

Comment: this might sound silly but.. why do you have to add this twice? won't that increment it by two?

Comment: Yeah, that's what he wanted.  :-)  If you only want it to bump once, then only add it once.

Comment: Oh, that's why then, it was already provided, lol. I'll edit it into my answer as well when I get to my computer.

Comment: So looking back over this, I ended up writing this script using a combination of different sources as well as testing on my end.  I used three lines of your script (which showed how to read/write too/from the plist) but had to find a way to actually answer his question. It isn't like I just copied your script (which is how you make it sound in your comment).

Comment: I disagree, there is more than 3 lines, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: In Xcode 5, you can skip the `if [ $CONFIGURATION == Release ]; then` check and add this to the Post-actions of your Archive scheme instead (Project > Scheme > Edit Scheme…).

Comment: @starkos yes - works better here, because `if [ $CONFIGURATION == Release ]` will ONLY work if your Archive Build Configuration is set to "Release"... Sometimes we want to create a "Debug" archive for internal testing via TestFlight. Just remember to set "Provide build settings from" to your default target, so it has access to the variables.

Answer (score 23):

This is very similar to @Inafziger's answer, but a more concise set of code, with the added benefit that the check for "Release" is done with a checkbox in XCode rather than a runtime variable:

[image]

Follow these instructions twice, ***dragging one to the beginning and one to the end*** (one to run before build and one to run after build):

```
# xcode-build-bump.sh
# @desc Auto-increment the build number every time the project is run. 
# @usage
# 1. Select: your Target in Xcode
# 2. Select: Build Phases Tab
# 3. Select: Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script
# 4. Paste code below in to new "Run Script" section
# 5. Drag the "Run Script" below "Link Binaries With Libraries"
# 6. Ensure that your starting build number is set to a whole integer and not a float (e.g. 1, not 1.0)
# 7. Check the checkbox "Run script only when installing"

buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

See https://gist.github.com/sekati/3172554

Comment: I also had great success adding this script to the Post-Actions of the scheme as suggested by @starkos above. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `${PROJECT_DIR}/` part of the paths if getting `Print: Entry, "CFBundleVersion", Does Not Exist`.

Comment: Question: Why exactly do it twice?

Comment: See the OP. It asked to have the build number incremented before and after the build

Comment: @ccwasden Increment the build number is only after the archive, is there any way to do it before?

Comment: @evya Create a build script as described, then drag it to be one of the first scripts to run (eg. before "link binaries with libraries") if you want it to run before

Answer (score 13):

Xcode includes [the command line tool `agvtool` to increase version numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html). So you don't have to do everything manually with `PListBuddy`.

`xcrun agvtool next-version -all`

increases your build number.

`xcrun agvtool new-marketing-version 2.0`

sets a new user visible version number.

See the [full documentation for details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html).

Comment: Should I add this script before or after the build?

Comment: Before. You want the new version to be included.

Comment: Wow - amazed this doesn't have more votes, it's seemingly the perfect answer.  Thanks @orkoden

Comment: Although cleaner than @ccwasden 's solution, this one makes xcode reload the xcodeproj and collapse the grouping in the left navigator everytime I build (Xcode 9.1 9B55)