# Xcode 6 archive process does not fire pre/post/build phase script for auto build increment

Tags: ios, shell, xcode6, teamcity

There are lot of questions about increment the build number in xcode, e.g.

[Xcode-Increment build number only during ARCHIVE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855955/xcode-increment-build-number-only-during-archive)

https://pontifex.azurewebsites.net/xcode-auto-increment-build-on-archive/

https://gist.github.com/sekati/3172554

I also follow same thing and its works fine when I do the release/debug. But when I do the archives I could not get incremental version numbers. Please see below pic for your reference.

I tried below scenarios

1. I wrote script in build phase

[image]

2. I wrote script in edit scheme->target->archive->pre action/post action

[image]

None of above will updating build version in archives. But after archives I have notices info.plist file in xcode project was updated with correct version number but If I open organizer and see archive it showed me old build number.

Note: In pic I have assign buildNumber as static during testing if I changed this version number still it does not updating during archive process.

Let me know if I am missing something here?

Comment: I would love to know what the solution to this is too!